# C - Having trouble with passing NxN array as an argument. I keep getting warning: incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I wrote this program that is supposed to sort NxN array. It gets compiled but doesn't work because the pointer type is incompatible.

I just need help with the pointers as argument. I get incompatible pointer type warning for both functions `swap` and `dblArraySort`. Any idea why is that ?

thanks in advance !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
swap(int **a, int **b)
{
    int temp;

    temp = **a;
    **a = **b;
    **b = temp;
}

void
dblArraySort(int **dblArray, int arrLen)
{
    int chkIndex;
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrLen; j++) {
                chkIndex = dblArray[i][j];

                for (k = 1; k + j < arrLen; k++)
                    if (chkIndex < dblArray[i][k + j])
                        swap(&dblArray[i][j], &dblArray[i][k + j]);
                    else
                        continue;
            }
        } else {
            for (j = 0; j < arrLen; j++) {
                chkIndex = dblArray[i][j];

                for (k = 1; k + j < arrLen; k++)
                    if (chkIndex >= dblArray[i][k + j])
                        swap(&dblArray[i][j], &dblArray[i][k + j]);
                    else
                        continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

int
main()
{
    unsigned int arrayLength;

    printf("Provide array size: \n");
    scanf("%d", &arrayLength);

    int doubleArray[arrayLength][arrayLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &doubleArray[i][j]);
        }
    }

    dblArraySort(doubleArray, arrayLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {
            printf("%d ", doubleArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried the code mentioned above

Comment: _"expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int *'"_ - You should make warnings into errors to not even let it compile such a mismatch. You also use the wrong format string in your `scanf`. Since you read into an `unsigned`, use `"%u"`, not `"%d"`

Comment: In order to gauge your level of understanding of your own code and make a suitable answer, please explain your understanding of this `&dblArray[i][j]` which you give as a parameter to swap(). Explain the semantic meaning and the syntactical aspects. Then compare it to the expectation of `**int`.

Comment: Note that `int **` does **not** refer to any two-dimensional array.  It refers to a *pointer* to an array of one or more `int *` *pointers*, each of which refer to individual and separate one-dimensional arrays of one or more actual `int` values.  See [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in C can be confusing. The thing you need to worry about is ***element type***.

- The element type of `int ** dblArray` is `int *`. In other words, `dblArray` is an array of `int *`s.
- However, the element type of `int doubleArray[arrayLength][arrayLength]` is `int row_type[arrayLength]`. That is not an `int *`, that is an array, which is a totally different thing.

Moreover, when you use an array⟶pointer conversion, as happens when you say:

```
dblArraySort(doubleArray, arrayLength);  // doubleArray is converted to a pointer
```

You get a pointer to *the array*, which in this case is a pointer to the innermost element type, an `int` — which is also not an `int *`.

**tl;dr**: You are trying to pass an array of *array of int* to a function taking an array of *pointer to int*. That won’t work.

---

I would like to comment on your variable naming as well. When you say “double” or “dbl”, as in `doubleArray` and `dblArray` the very first thing people will think is that you are handling a linear array of type double, which is *also* not what the array is.

You have there a two-dimensional array. Not a “double” array. Common naming for such thing would be `array2D` or `matrix`.

---

To make it work you need either C11, which allows you to pass a VLA as:

```
void sort_array2D( size_t rows, size_t columns, int array[rows][columns] )
{
  ...
  int value = array[i][j];
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  int array2D[Array_Length][Array_Length];
  ...
  sort_array2D( Array_Length, Array_Length, array2D );
```

Or you need to simply assume you must compute the index manually. A little function will help:

```
size_t index2D( size_t rows, size_t columns, size_t r, size_t c )
{
  (void)rows; // (quiet the compiler about not using this argument)
  return r * columns + c;
}
```

Then you can write your function as:

```
void sort_array2D( int * array, size_t rows, size_t columns )
{
  ...
  int value = array[index2D( rows, columns, i, j )];
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  int array2D[Array_Length][Array_Length];
  ...
  sort_array2D( (int *)array2D, Array_Length, Array_Length );
```

I haven’t bothered to analyze your sort function. It doesn’t look right to me, but honestly, I’ve barely glanced at it. Calling a value from the array `chkIndex` looks fishy, since the values of the array are not ***indices** per se*, at least not in the context of sorting them.

Remember, when messing with arrays in C you need to keep strict care to not mix up the *type* of the elements. (Or the types of things in general, whether syntactic or conceptual.)

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed answer, thanks !